# Supplying varying number of input arguments for np.meshgrid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a function that uses `np.meshgrid` to get the matrix form of supplied co-ordinates. I have a parameter `dim` that determines what dimension I am working with and needs to return an array with `dim` dimension along axis 1. I have attached an MWE below.

```
import numpy as np

def func(dim=2):
    a = [1, 2]
    return np.array(np.meshgrid([a]*dim)).T.reshape(-1, dim)

func()
"""
returns
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]])
"""
```

However my expected output is

```
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

, which is obtained by replacing `return np.array(np.meshgrid([a]*dim)).T.reshape(-1, dim)` with `return np.array(np.meshgrid(a, a)).T.reshape(-1, dim)`. Notice that I passed in `(a, a)` as the parameters to `np.meshgrid`, because `dim=2`. If `dim=3`, the input would be `(a, a, a)` and so on.

How can I achieve this? If any other function can do this, I am open to that as well. Thanks.

Comment: Look at the `[a]*dim` and `meshgrid` parts first (even show the to us), before moving on to the transpose and reshape.  Get the small steps right first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the difference between these:

```py
def print_args(*args):
    print(args)

a = [1, 2]
print_args([a] * 2)
# ([[1, 2], [1, 2]],)

print_args(*[a] * 2)
# ([1, 2], [1, 2])
```

In the first one you are passing a list of lists. In the second one you are [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) (the first `*` in `func`) the list so each sub-list is a positional argument.

```py
def func(dim=2):
    a = [1, 2]
    return np.array(np.meshgrid(*[a] * dim)).T.reshape(-1, dim)

func()
# array([[1, 1],
#        [1, 2],
#        [2, 1],
#        [2, 2]])
```